# how to show a tpl from an xtype?

Tags: javascript, extjs, items

I have this on my MatchDetail.js:

```
items:[{
   xtype: 'matchdetailtpl',
   flex: 1
},
```

and this on my MatchDetailTpl.js:

```
tpl:new Ext.XTemplate([
   '<tpl for=".">',
      '<div>',
         '<div><h1>{firstName} {lastName}</h1> from {league} - <i>{division}</i></div>',
      '</div>',
   '</tpl>',
].join(''))
```

if i place the tpl on my MatchDetail.js config:{} it show's up properly, but once I structured it like my example above. All I get is a blank 'card'.

How should this be handled so that the tpl would show up?

Answer (score 1):

The "xtype" will create an instance of the class with that alias.  I assume that class is what the rest of the contents of MathDetailTpl.js contains (you are only showing us one piece of the configuration).

Assuming your MathDetailTpl class is indeed an Ext.Component, you might just need to provide `data` to the instance of the class so that the `tpl` gets rendered.  You could also try using `renderTpl` and `renderData`.

Post the contents of MathDetailTpl.js, and perhaps more of how you are using it in the `items` array from the first code block for more help.

*UPDATE*

Based on your comment, you are trying to use a centralized store with an XTemplate.  The magic glue you are looking for is a Ext.DataView (or Ext.view.View in Ext 4).

```
Ext.define('MatchDetail', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    alias: 'widget.matchDetail',

    itemSelector: 'div.match-detail',
    tpl:new Ext.XTemplate([
       '<tpl for=".">',
          '<div class="match-detail">',
             '<div><h1>{firstName} {lastName}</h1> from {league} - <i>{division}</i></div>',
          '</div>',
       '</tpl>',
    ].join(''))
});
```

Then later, you should be able to do:

```
...
items: [{
    xtype: 'matchDetail',
    store: myCentralizedStore
}] 
...
```

The `itemSelector` attribute is required for DataView's, which is why I added a class to the div for each item in the template.

Comment: You are right about data. Apparently the data from my store is not being passed to MatchDetailTpl.js ... I placed the tpl on the MatchDetailTpl.js and tried to call it from MatchDetail.js

In retro, there are 3 files ... index.html (has the list), MatchDetail.js (container which handles items), and MatchDetailTpl.js (containing the tpl)

If the data is placed together with the tpl, they show up correctly. But what I need is to use a centralized data which is found on my store making different view component share the same store, whose reference is made accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Solved it! apparently my xtype from the code below on my controller is not targeted to the correct view .js file

showDetail: function(list, record) {
  this.getMain().push({
           xtype: 'matchdetail',
        })
}